# How to do a delay on a for loop that makes dynamic number of div's on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a delay on each iteration on a Script that makes dynamic div's based on elements of an array that has some links to images on it, to achieve some kind of effect like the one in GameCube console intro where a div appears one by one and not all at the same time.

i've tried with setTimeout() and Async functions but they just dont work

```js
var arraydas  = ["aviso1.jpg","aviso2.jpg","a","s","s",2,3,4];

var array = ["sYDqBU1.jpg","t1LuvGZ.jpg","l660ATK.jpg","iNWWr7b.jpg"]


var htmlElements = "";
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   htmlElements += '<div class="box"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/'+array[i]+'" width="100%" height="100%"></div>';
}
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = htmlElements;
```

```css
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.box {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 
</div>
```

Comment: I'd stay with `setTimeout` - you simply need to use it within a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a timer and not a loop. Because the timer will run over and over, it creates the effect of a loop, but with the added benefit of doing it on your time scale.

```js
var array = ["sYDqBU1.jpg","t1LuvGZ.jpg","l660ATK.jpg","iNWWr7b.jpg"]

// This will keep track of the currently displayed array index
let counter = 0; 

let container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeDiv(){
  // If we've reached the end of the array, stop the timer
  if(counter >= array.length-1) { clearInterval(timer); }
  
  // Don't build HTML strings, create DOM elements
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  
  // Configure their properties
  div.classList.add("box");
  
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/" + array[counter];
  
  // And append them to the DOM
  div.appendChild(img);
  container.appendChild(div);
  
  // Increase the counter
  counter++;
}

// Start the timer
let timer = setInterval(makeDiv, 1000);
```

```css
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.box {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}

div > img { width:100%;  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Hola kaskdkasdkasdk
</div>
```

Comment: But it's even better _not_ to use `setInterval` and instead use a function that shifts an element from the list, and itself on a new `setTimeout` if that didn't lead to an empty list. If you need limited recurrence, use `setTimeout`. (If you need infinite recurrence, _maybe_ use `setInterval`, but you probably still want `setTimeout` anyway)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I agree that `.setTimeout()` is the better choice. I didn't suggest it here because you need to get into recursive calls and you need to put safeguards in place to prevent multiple timers from running. As this OP is clearly new to this, `setInterval()` solves the problem without side-effects and is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would continue to use `setTimeout` to control the delay you want to apply. The function should determine if we need to keep processing more array items:

**Snippet**

```js
var array = ["sYDqBU1.jpg", "t1LuvGZ.jpg", "l660ATK.jpg", "iNWWr7b.jpg"]

var container = document.getElementById("container");

var current = 0;

function getEm() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  setTimeout(() => {
    div.innerHTML = `<div class="box"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/${array[current]}" width="100%" height="100%"></div>`
    container.appendChild(div);

    current++
    if (current < array.length) {
      getEm();
    }
  }, 500);
}

getEm();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.box {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: You've provided no explanation for how your code works and the use of Arrow Functions and template literals is clearly going to be over the OPs head here.

Comment: Thank you very much, i think i'll stick to this solution as i can use it for other stuff i may use on future

Comment: Also, what happens if `getEm()` were to get called more than once?

Comment: Think you projecting a little. It's actually not a "problem". OP will be fine and I am not going to give a line-by-line explanation for elementary items that they are encountering in every library and package today - it's 2019. Let's leave it there and you have a great day.